# Failed to initialize DataContext in Silverlight RIA app (PDC'09)

Tags: c#, web-services, ria

I'm using Silverlight Business app template with RIA services (PDC'09 release).
I've created DomainService, let's call it *ListingDomainService* (based on EF model).
Then build the solution.

Ok, now I can in SL project

```
         private void GenerateReport_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
         {

          ListingDomainContext reportContext = new ListingDomainContext();
          ...
         }
```

The problem is that periodically it fails to compile: reportContext  becomes unavaliable.

I've included Generated_Code folder in project and added reference to the *WebProject*.Web.Services

Can it be a bug of RIA services or its smth else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys, the problem was that I tried to pass array of bytes via service thus Web app didn't built and as a result it didn't generate code in Generated_Code